# Dynamic creation of EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

My problem is actually simple but I really do not find a good solution to it.

I've currently to manage several DB in my application:

- one UNIQUE admin DB (with a static name);
- one client DB, with a name depending on the client.

I'm using JPA and I would like to create dynamically EntityManagers for client DB. But when I create this programmatically, I get this error:
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: joinTransaction has been called on a resource-local EntityManager which is unable to register for a JTA transaction.

Here is the code:

```
@Stateful
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{

private EntityManagerFactory emf;
private EntityManager em;

@PostConstruct      // automatically called when EJB constructed and session starts
public void init() {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("punit");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
}
...
```

And

```
@Stateful(mappedName = "CustomerService")
public class CustomerServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

@Override
public void create(Customer cust) {
    getEm().joinTransaction();
    getEm().persist(cust);
}
```

More generally, I'v got problems with JPA. I just would like to connect to two databases, do some CRUD operations on them. But I really don't know how to manage transactions (my first approach was to let the container manage it...).

If someone could help me, could be great!

NB: I'm using a Glassfish Java EE server and PGSql DBs.

Answer (score 1):

In jpa, you can declare several prsistenceunits in the persistence.xml file.

At the point of injection, you can do something like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "unitName0", properties={@PersistenceProperty(...)}
EntityManager emClient;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "unitName1", properties={@PersistenceProperty(...)}
EntityManager emAdmin;
```

This way, you dont have to create the entity managers manually, hence you get the container transaction management.

NOT TESTED:

If you have dynamic database names, you would inject EntityManagerFactory

@PersistenceContext(unitName ="name")
EntityManagerFactory emf;

//at the point you want the EntityManager

```
Map<String, String> props; //put the connection property for the EM here
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(props);
```

Based on the fact that in a J2EE environment we use the concept of DataSources, and ConnectionPooling, it would be nearly impossible to implement this kind of dynamic datasources, without resorting to manual creation of entitymanagerfactory.

This is my reasoning:
The server manages the connection pooling, and the jpa provider (such as eclipselink) uses jndi to determine the connection to the database. This implies that if you were to change the database name, then it must also have a connection pooling resources, and an associated jdbc resource. This will ofcourse negate what you want to do.

Basic solution: Create EntityManagerFactory manually and manually manage transactions.
Specify in the persistence xml that the unit is non-jta for this to work.

Then you can programmatically supply connection data based on user-session:

Something of this sort:

//this must be session specific.

```
class PersistenceSession{
  static Map<String, String> clientSessionProps;

  //When new session starts and a new client has logged in.
  static void setClientConnectionProperties(Client client){
    .....
  }

  static Map<String, String> getClientSessionProps(){
   return clientSessionProps;
  }
}
```

At the ejb level.

```
@Stateless
   public class TestEntityFacade extends AbstractFacade<TestEntity> {


    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @PostConstruct
    void init(){
      emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("name");
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            return emf.createEntityManager(PersistenceSession.getClientSessionProps());
    }

    public TestEntityFacade() {
        super(TestEntity.class);
    }

     void add(Entity e){

        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        .....
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I'm aware of this approach, but I will not know the name of the client DB (the choice of the DB will be done by the application). So I can't use the @PersistenceContext annotation, which requires a static name.

Comment: Did check the edit? Where you can supply the connection properties when creating the EntityManager from the injected EMF? Couldnt this solve the dynamic table issue?

Comment: Yes, I checked it.
But if I inject an EMF, I've to indicate the unitName property: I can't do this because I don't know the name of the persistence unit, this is a dynamic parameter

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I think I will have to use stateless as you said. 
But what I wanted to say about DB is that new DB will appear (new clients). So I've already created a script which creates a new connection poo and the data resource (with asadmin command).
I'll have to edit the persistence.xml file, but it could be done.

So the remaining issue is how to create the entity manager linked to this new data resource. 

I'm sorry, I didn't explain it very well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually very neat way how to do this is with CDI [Producers](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/java-ee-cdi-producer-methods-tutorial.html), you can define a bean which will produce for your any number of custom Entity Managers, see the example.

```
@SessionScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {

     @Produces
     @AdminDB
     @PersistenceContext(unitName = "adminDB")
     public EntityManaged adminDB;

     @Produces
     @UserDB
     @PersistenceContext(unitName = "userDB")
     public EntityManaged userDB;
}
```

This means that these two EntityManagers get created within every user session and than you can inject them to any bean with

```
@Inject
@UserDB
private EntityManager em; //if you want to use UserDB now
```

`@UserDB` and `@AdminDB` are your own defined [Qualifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html). This leads to much more easier and readable code.