# EJB jpa Dynamic creation of EntityManager

Tags: jpa, ejb

My problem is actually simple but I really do not find a good solution to it.

I've currently to manage several DB in my application:

- one UNIQUE admin DB (with a static name);
- one client DB, with a name depending on the client.

I'm using JPA 2.0 genericdao and ejb3 and I would like to create (produce) dynamically EntityManagers for client DB.

The first entytymanger (properties saved in persistence.xml) to find the the client DB properties ( name, login, password, dialect ... ) stored in the admin DB.

I want to use 
@PersistenceContext(name = "nscloud_PU",type= PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED )

and ejb3 to resolve the LazyInitializationException

Comment: Have you looked into VPD multitenant type solutions?  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_multitenant.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic creation of EntityManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572705/dynamic-creation-of-entitymanager)